# What's the most efficient algorithm to check the number of cycles of length 4 in an undirected graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

What's the most efficient algorithm to check the number of cycles of length 4 in an undirected, unweighted graph?

Comment: @JohnHughes, I was actually interested in the fastest possible algorithm to do so in terms of time complexity. I have edited the question for clarity. Sorry for any confusion and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also go this way: for any vertex $v\in V$, store a bitmask $b_v$ that encodes the positions of its neighbours with a bit $1$. Then run over all the couples $(v_i,v_j)$ with $i\neq j$ and let $N_{i,j}$ be the number of bits $1$ that $b_i$ and $b_j$ share. The number of cycles of length $4$ is given by:
$$ \frac{1}{4}\sum_{i,j}\binom{N_{i,j}}{2}.$$
This is obviously a $O(n^2)$ algorithm both in memory and in time, where $n$ is the number of vertices of the original graph. However, if the graph is very sparse or structured, it may be convenient to compute the number of $4$-cycles through $\text{Tr}(M^2)$ and $\text{Tr}(M^4)$ where $M$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph. I think this is the optimal strategy for [sum graphs](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/sum3.pdf) and Paley graphs, and for every graph whose [spectrum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphSpectrum.html) is known in advance.

Comment: Tr(M) seems to be 0.  Is it enough to just compute $M^2$ along the way or is computing its trace also necessary?

Comment: @svsring: no, it is not: since there are no loops, $\text{Tr}(M)=0$.

Comment: What is not?  Tr(M) IS zero.  Why is it necessary to compute the trace of $M$ and of $M^2$?

Comment: @svsring: it is not necessary to compute tre trace of $M$ since it is obviously zero, but we need the trace of $M^4$ and the diagonal elements of $M^2$ to compute the number of $4$-cycles. Better now?

Comment: Yes, that sounds fine.

Comment: There are $O(n^2)$ pairs of bitmasks and for each pair you have to find the number of shared 1s. How do you do this exactly?

Comment: @ArturRyazanov: through the elementary operation given by the bitwise $\text{and}$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this is the fastest possible, but this is how I'd do it if I had to do it fast: Use a hash map that maps pairs of vertices to the number of paths of length $2$ between them. Iterate over the vertices, adding $1$ to the entry for each pair of neighbours of the vertex. Then iterate over the entries, summing $\binom n2$ of the counts $n$. Divide the total by $2$ since you've counted each $4$-cycle twice. (Of course if you're really after speed you'd sum $n(n-1)$ and divide by $4$ in the end.)

Comment: Sorry for removing the "accepted" for this answer; would you mind stating the time complexity of your algorithm? Is it $O(V^2)?$

Comment: @MaxLi: I would have thought the time complexity is immediate from the description. It's linear in the number of vertices and the number of paths of length $2$, and $O(n\log n)$ in the number of pairs of vertices with a common neighbour (since it needs one hash entry for each such pair). If most pairs of vertices have a common neighbour, you can use an array instead of the hash map; that version is just $O(n)$ in the number of pairs of vertices (since you need to iterate over that array).

Comment: @MaxLi: In response to your updated comment with $O\left(V^2\right)$: You can make it $O\left(V^2\right)$ (where $V$ is the number of vertices) if you want by using an array (see above), but if only few pairs of vertices share a neighbour, it's more efficient to use the hash map and make it $O(n\log n)$ in the number of such pairs.

Comment: Thanks joriki, I'm a novice. +1

Comment: @MaxLi: Actually, if you have enough space, you can also make it $O\left(V^2\right)$ by making the hash map big enough that the overhead is linear in the number of items added; then you have both cases covered efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, you have been more than helpful joriki.